# Why is my question still on hold?

Tags: discussion

Why is my [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986295/is-it-possible-to-download-packages-after-ubtuntu-has-been-installed-with-try-u?noredirect=1#comment1589499_986295) still on hold after a day?  I made it more specific.

Comment: When I reviewed it, I felt it was a duplicate of the question I linked in my comment. So I voted to leave closed.

Comment: It is closed as "unclear what you are asking" but it appears clear perhaps with revisions OP made . It may be a duplicate as Muru points out but in the mean time VTR now and then we can VTC as duplicate later? Could a mod step in and change the close reason?

Answer (score 6):

Just follow this advice:

> Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to
>   highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard
>   to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help
>   clarifying this question. If this question can be reworded to fit the
>   rules in the [help center](https://askubuntu.com/help/closed-questions), please [edit the question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/986295/edit).

This message tells you what you can and need to do in order to get your question reopened:

1. You should take the [Tour](https://askubuntu.com/tour) to make yourself familiar with the site.
2. You should read [How do I ask a good question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) to make sure you make your question a valuable one.

   1. [Search](https://askubuntu.com/search?q="AppStream+cache+update+failed"), and research
      In your case it would be helpful to search for the main error message – `AppStream cache update failed` – on [AU](https://askubuntu.com/search?q="AppStream+cache+update+failed") as well as [the internet](https://www.startpage.com/rvd/search?query="AppStream%20cache%20update%20failed"&language=en) in general. Try to get to the bottom of the problem and include the *whole* result of your research in your question. Please do *not* use comments to add information, instead [edit the question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/986295/edit) directly.
   2. Be on-topic ✓
   3. Be specific
      If you find other resources which cover your problem (like [Unable to 'apt-get dist-upgrade' on a persistent Ubuntu 16.04 USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761592/unable-to-apt-get-dist-upgrade-on-a-persistent-ubuntu-16-04-usb) in your case) and they don't solve your problem, include them and explain how *exactly* the solutions proposed there don't work for you. Show us what you tried.
   4. Make it relevant to others ✓
   5. Keep an open mind
      Believe it or not, but we're really trying hard to help you here – we just need you to help us help you.